# Problems with unixODBC and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, odbc

I installed unixodbc, sqlite3 and libsqliteodbc.

odbcinst.ini looks like this:

```
[SQLite]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=libsqliteodbc.so
Setup=libsqliteodbc.so
UsageCount=2

[SQLite3]
Description=SQLite3 ODBC Driver
Driver=libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=libsqlite3odbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

odbc.ini looks like this:

```
[mysqlitedb]
Description=My SQLite database
Driver=SQLite3
Database=/my_database.db
```

When I test connection like this:

```
isql -v mysqlitedb
```

it says Connected!

But when I try a SELECT statement it says:

```
SQL> select * from user
[S1000][SQLite]no such table: user (1)
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLPrepare
```

What is wrong?

I known the table: user is present, because I get results when I do this:

```
sqlite3 /my_database.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from user;
1|admin|password
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this on OS X with unixodbc-2.3.4, sqliteodbc-0.9994, and a database in my `$HOME`, nor with the database in `/`. (i.e it works as expected)

Answer (score 0):

You sure about this path in your `odbc.ini` file?

```
Database=/my_database.db
```

I would make sure that you don't need to specify the actual path to the sqlite DB file there.

Comment: Now I am not sure how isql works. I set the path to a database that does not exists. It says Connected! There are no tables in the database, so I create some and then I quit isql. I search the disk to see if the a database is create, but I do not find any.

Comment: @DánjalSalbergAdlersson - [Examples I'm finding on the net](http://unixodbc.13851.n7.nabble.com/unixODBC-Setup-on-Gentoo-td2470.html) show it as a full path. So that would be putting that file at the `/` directory. Can you confirm if it's there or not? Also you can locate files often times using this command `locate my_database.db`.

Comment: @DánjalSalbergAdlersson - another example: http://lojze.lugos.si/~darja/software/r/library/RODBC/README

Comment: I tried changing location of DB and changing full path, but it still does not work. I check for leading spaces in config, but that did not help. I am wondering if there is something wrong with the drivers? I checked the dependencies of the drivers and they seem OK.

Comment: @DánjalSalbergAdlersson - I tried to set this up on my Fedora 19 system and I haven't gotten it working yet either. Was there a guide you were following for the setup? This combination seems unused, I found very little info on unixODBC + sqlite.

Comment: I googled around and found things here and there and peaced them together. I do not have the links.

Comment: My `odbc.ini` had spaces for indenting. I removed all and this solved error `S1000 no such table` for me. Interestingly the `odbcinst.ini` seems to work fine with spaces however?